# Nvidia toolkit for download

Tags: windows, download, nvidia, toolkit

There is someone who can give me a link in Mega with the nvidias cuda toolkit for windows 10.
I have tried to download but the problem is that it is 1.4gb, 
You can post it, or send the link to my email r.mendez@estudiantes.matcom.uh.cu

Comment: Offtopic for SO.

Comment: Where may i put the question?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal ?

Comment: I cant doit. By the size. And by my country. Nvidia blocks Cuba

Comment: the size is the same, wherever you get it.  And its the other way round according to this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Cuba .Condolencences. What is this Mega you want in uploaded to?

Comment: I refer to mega.nz

Comment: The article you cite is, sorry my words, bulk shit. There is not censorchip of the internet by the side of Cuba. The problem is the treasure department of usa, which blocks cknecctions to a lot of sites, among them, anyone that use strong cryptography. And in adittion, there are limitations of bandwith, because usa enterprise being incapable of make bussines with our coumtry by their restrictives laws.

Comment: Among this sites is nvidia website. I cant use a webproxy, or a vpn, but the conections is not stable, and nvidias website do not have restarting download. The site mega.nz do have it. My request is to someone to share with me a link on this site to download it.

Comment: *mutter* always new never to trust wikipedia ;o)